# Run a .exe after installation using Orca

Tags: orca

I have a msi file im trying to embed an .bat file converted to .exe

what I've done so far in orca>

add binary

set name, put in binary data(pointed the .exe)

went into customaction

set actionname, type 2, sourcename, left target empty

went into installexecutesequence

put in my actionname, left condition empty, put in sequence After installfinalize 6600

I put in 6601

now when I run this MSI.

installs the software, but my .exe doesn't run until I hit the uninstall button and prompts a message saying:

A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected

any idea what im doing wrong?

I want to have this MSI run the .exe after installation.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume this EXE is manipulating the system in any way, which means you need to change the CustomAction Type to 3074 and place it before InstallFinalize.

Does this script need to run on installation, uninstallation and repair? 
If only during installation: set NOT REMOVE as condition.

Anyways: It is not a good idea to embedd a compiled batch file into a MSI file. Most actions you need to do can be done using Standard Windows Installer functions. If you need to add functionality to the MSI at least don't compile the batch file for the following reasons:

- nobody knows what the batch is doing
- no standard logging for this batch file
- no uninstallation/repair of what the batch is doing
- no customization of the batch possible if needed